# Automate the process of exporting data from multiple CSV files in a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have already written a script to export data from a single CSV file into SQL Server.  I do have to provide the path for that CSV.

I'm trying to figure out how do I modify the code so that it checks a particular folder for CSV files, and then starts processing them one by one. After processing each file, it moves the original file to a different location.  Thanks in advance.

**Update:** 
I have a console application written that parses the CSV, connects to SQL database and inserts values. But like I said I have to give the file path. I'm looking for a way to provide only a folder name and the application should look for any CSV files in that folder, parses each file, exports data to SQL, once done moves that file to a different folder and then starts with the next file.

Comment: There is too much data parsing and data manipulation that I need to do on those CSV files. SSIS is not an option. I have to write a script.

Comment: I don't think file operations can be performed using sql script. the best options could be creating a console application and calling that using a sql job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For migrate data from csv try `bulk insert`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188365.aspx

For example

```
bulk insert [tableName] from 'c:\test.csv'
With (
         FIELDTERMINATOR =',',
         FIRSTROW=1
)
```

Comment: Inserting data from a single CSV is not an issue, I already have a console application written for that. Do you know how to process multiple CSVs from a single folder one at a time?

Comment: `string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\Dir\", "*.csv");`
And process each file

Comment: Any idea how would I read and store the name of the CSV that's being processed to keep track of it?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Just read about the GetFiles() & EnumerateFiles() classes.  Thanks!